# Plot sample-vs-sample gene expression levels in R

Tags: r

I have a data set containing gene expression data for various genes, across 24 different samples. In my current dataframe, each row is a gene and each column is a sample.

I want to create a dot plot where each dot is a gene, the y-axis represents the expression of that gene in sample A, and the x-axis represents the expression of the same gene in sample B.

I have tried to search for this but don't know what such a plot is called or how I can find it. Most of my other plots are plotted with ggplot2, but it does not matter what package is used to solve the problem.

Example data:

```
sample_A<-c(2,3,1)
sample_B<-c(-1,4,-3)
genes <- c("gene1","gene2","gene3")
df<-data.frame(sample_A,sample_B,row.names = genes)
```

Data frame:

```
      sample_A sample_B
gene1        2       -1
gene2        3        4
gene3        1       -3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_point` with ggplot2 is probably what you're looking for.  The dots can also be labelled using `geom_label`.

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = sample_B, y = sample_A))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_label(aes(label = rownames(df)))
```

Comment: Wow, how could I have missed that.